# Heroku Getting Cron Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've got a (free) cronjob running on a Heroku app and I'm trying to get the logs as they ran, but there doesn't seem to be any easy way to get the most recent logs of a cronjob.

On the [heroku website](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron#inspecting_output) it says `heroku logs --ps cron.1`

But it seems like each cron instance creates a new process, it's now at cron.51. Running `heroku logs --ps cron.51` works, but I don't want to have to keep track of the numbers.

Is there a way to get the logs of the most recent cronjob run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `heroku logs --ps cron`.

That way you get a consolidated log of all cron processes as opposed to one with a specific id.

Comment: Nowadays the process name to filter by is 'scheduler', as Heroku have deprecated their cron based system.